# Update column with value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

In a SQL table I have two columns: the first contain a path and the second contains a value.

| colunm1 | /path/ |
| --- | --- |
| colunm2 | 12345 |

I need to update the first column with the value that exists in the second column. to get this result :

| colunm1 | /path/12456/ |
| --- | --- |

I tried this, but not working

```
update tablename p
set p.colunm1 = "/path/'colunm2'/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use CONCAT

```
update tablename p
set p.colunm1 = CONCAT("/path/",`colunm2`,"/");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but the SQL you shared uses column2 as a string literal. You could use the [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate the two columns:

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET    column1 = CONCAT(column1, column2)
```